# How to suppress "macro redefined" warning in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macros, clang, warnings, llvm

I need to redefine a macro in my project and have a compile warning. I've tried

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wall"
#define SomeMacroToRedefine MyMacro
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

But it doesn't really work and I still have a warning. Any other ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should consider using a unique identifier instead.

This warning apparently has no identifier in the Xcode 6.1 distribution.

You can `#undef` prior to your definition:

```
#undef SomeMacroToRedefine
#define SomeMacroToRedefine MyMacro
```